# Beginner at kinect - matlab : Kinect does not start

Tags: matlab, kinect

hello I am trying to set up kinect1 in matlab environment and I cannot get joint coordinates out of kinect even though I have a preview of the captured depth. In the preview it says " waiting to start" when I actually started the video. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different features which you don't want to mix up:

1. There is the preview function. By calling `preview(vid)` a preview window is opened and the camera runs.  The preview is there to help you set up your camera, point it to the right spot etc. When you're finished with that, close the preview manually or via `closepreview(vid)`.
2. When you are ready for image acquisition, call `start(vid)`. With `img = getdata(vid,1)` you can then read 1 frame from the camera and save it to `img`. When you're finished with acquisition, call `close(vid)` to stop the camera.

The camera itsself starts capturing images as soon as `start` is called, so even if you wait some seconds after calling start, the first image will be the one captured right then. There exist several properties to control the acquisition, it is best to have a look at all properties of `vid`.

You can manually specify a trigger to take an image by first setting `triggerconfig(vid,'manual')`, then starting the camera and finally calling `trigger(vid)` to take an image.

The number of frames that is acquired after calling `start` or `trigger` is specified by the `FramesPerTrigger` parameter of `vid`. To continuously acquire images, set it to `inf`. It is possible to use `getdata` to read any number of frames, e.g. `getdata(vid,5);`. Note that this only works if 5 frames are actually available on the camera. You get the number of available frames from the `FramesAvailable` property of `vid`.

You can put the image acquisition inside a `for` loop to continuously acquire images

```
n = 1000;
vid = videoinput('kinect',2);
set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',n);
start(vid);
for k=1:n
    img = getdata(vid,1);
    % do magic stuff with img
end
stop(vid);
```

Comment: So matlab get only the information of the image when I type command  getdata, for a continuous set of of data I need to use a  loop I quess?